# Visual Studio 2015, Error while executing project... Debugger Error

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

Sorry for my bad English. I was trying to translate an error message to English.
The error I get if I try to "Start" and Debug my project is:

> Error while executing project: The program  could not be started. No data available.

[image: The Error]

The other thing is that this happens to all my projects and solutions.
I also tried to reset to default settings and I tried to disable all extensions.
But no luck.

Comment: Maybe repair/reinstall VS?

Comment: Unfortunately It didn't work the repair.

Comment: Have you selected the project as startup project before running the program?

Comment: what type of project?

Comment: Visual C# Project - Windows Forms.

Comment: @Liwu, Not debug your app, just run it using "start without debugging(Ctrl+F5)", how about the result? Could you find the .exe file in your project folder? If you double click it, does it run normally? Please also close all third party tools or processes(antivirus or others) in your windows, debug it again.

Comment: The *.exe file is there. But strangely no *.vhost.exe file.

Comment: @Liwu, Do you enable the project property "Enable Visual studio hosting process"? As far as I know, the host file was related to this option. But like my previous suggestion, could you run your app without debugging? Could you run the .exe directly?

Comment: @Liwu, What about this issue? Could you visit the output path in your project property? Is it the correct path? Do you have the enough access account for that folder? If you get any latest information, feel free to share it here.

Comment: @Liwu, Would you please share the latest information in your side?